# Hosting webpage from shared. Hyperlink to webpage after ? is not getting passed

Tags: javascript, html

Due to admin restrictions I have ended up creating a webpage on a shared folder using HTML and JavaScript.  This shared folder can be access by all.   What I have done is placed the *.html files in the given shared folder and link this file is now shared via email.  Something similar to sharing an excel or word file using the folder and file path.  In this case it open to a webpage.

Given below is the sample webpage link that I am trying to use.   I am trying to pass some values as well along with the file link.  As long as I copy and paste the link into IE or chrome it works with complete url, but if it is clicked from excel or outlook email with the exact same link every after the '?' goes missing.  Can someone help me to find a solution to be able to share a folder path with the content after '?' also being intact.

The content after the '?' will be used to populate the webpage that will open up.  Given below is the example of the hyperlink I am trying to create.

file://<>/Test.html?uid=2&age=24#

code that I am using.  Have intentionally removed the JavaScript tags.  As was unable to page it with it.

```
            function getParam(name)
        {  
            name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");  
            var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";  
            var regex = new RegExp( regexS );  
            var results = regex.exec(window.location.href);
            if(results == null)
                return "";  
            else    
                return results[1];
        }
      function getUrlData()
       {
            TestingApp.txtUID.value = getParam("uid");
            TestingApp.txtAge.value = getParam("age");
            alert('Hi world');
       }

</head>
<body>
   <h2 font face="Georgia, Garamond, Times New Roman" color="#FF0000">Testing</h2>

<font face="Verdana, Tahoma, Arial" size="3">
<form name="TestingApp">
  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
  <td width="100">UID:</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="txtUID" size="14"></td>
  <td width="100">Age:</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="txtAge" size="14"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td width="100">Full Name:</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="txtFullName" size="30"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td width="100"><br><br></td>
  <td>
    <input type="button" value="Show Full Name" onClick="getUrlData()">
  </td>
</tr>
  </table>
</form>
</font>

</body>
</html>
```

`

Answer (score 1):

You can create a wrap for page with parameters:

1. Create wrap.html and specify a link to page.html with parameters in *link* variable:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var link = "file:///C:/page.html?age=10&uid=777";
    document.location.href = link;
  </script>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

2. In Word or Excel document create hyperlink to wrap.html *without parameters*.

When you click on hyperlink in Word, wrap.html will redirect you to the page.html with parameters.

3. Create page.html:

   ```html
   <html>
   <head>
     <title>TestingApp</title>
     <style>
       .title {
         font-family: "Georgia", "Garamond", "Times New Roman";
         color: #FF0000;
       }
       .TestingApp {
         font-family: "Verdana", "Tahoma", "Arial";
         font-size: 1em;
       }
       .field {
         display: block;
         padding: 10px;
       }
     </style>
   </head>

   <body>
     <h2 class="title">Testing</h2>
     <form class="TestingApp" id="TestingApp">
       <div class="field">
         <label for="txtUID">UID:</label>
         <input type="text" id="txtUID" name="txtUID" size="14">
       </div>
       <div class="field">
         <label for="txtAge">Age:</label>
         <input type="text" id="txtAge" name="txtAge" size="14">
       </div>
       <div class="field">
         <label for="txtFullName">Full Name:</label>
         <input type="text" name="txtFullName" size="30">
       </div>
       <div class="field">
         <input type="button" value="Show Full Name" onClick="getUrlData()">
       </div>
     </form>
     <script>
       function getParam(name) {
         name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
         var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
         var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
         var results = regex.exec(window.location.href);
         return (results == null) ? "" : results[1];
       }

       function getUrlData() {
         document.getElementById("txtUID").value = getParam("uid");
         document.getElementById("txtAge").value = getParam("age");
       }
     </script>
   </body>

   </html>
   ```

P.S. Never use *table* to markup page. All styles should be declared in *style* tag or in external file

Comment: Hi,  This is really nice coding and does answer my question in part.  The parameters vary for each link and what parameters will be passed in their in excel file.  for example excel range A2 to A10 will contain UID and B2 to B10 will contain age.  Now in excel range C2 to C10 I would put a hyperlink formula something like this.  '=HYPERLINK("file:///C:/page.html?age="&B2&"&uid="&A2,"Click Here")' in C2.  But that being said this is really a instresting solution.  Let me work and see if I can incorporate your code in some other way as well.  really appreciate your time.

Comment: I was just thinking of a solution were our folder path can be treated as an url by the system instead of folder path.  that way the system will not auto clean anything after '?', but not sure how to make it happen.

Comment: Problem solved.  I have placing my html file in a SharePoint folder and it works like a magic.   But you still helped so going ahead and accepting your answer as well as technically you did answer my question..... :)